# ko.mapping is always an empty array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Here is what I am returning from my controller:

```
    var states = _dc.States.ToList();
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    ViewBag.StateList = serializer.Serialize(states);
```

My JS:

```
var stateList = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.StateList);
var stateListModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(stateList);
```

Is I do a `console.log` on `stateListModel`, it is always `[]`, but `stateList` is a complete array with all the data.

Comment: `stateListModel` will be an observable array which is a function so you need to log out with `console.log(stateListModel())`. If you do it is it still empty?

Comment: Can you show us what your JS model looks like too?

Answer (score 0):

The ko.mapping result is not an empty array, it is a function.

As nemesv's comment says, you have to do this:

```
var stateListModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(stateList);
var realArray = stateListModel();
```